# How do I maximize my report weight on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-abuse-reporting

I try to help out as best I can by reporting racist, homophobic, and other bigotted posts on Facebook. Unfortunately, none of my reports are triggering anything.

Does reporting too many things reduce the weight of my reports? If I held off on the isolated comments that may not be seen by other people, would my reports be more likely to trigger the algorithm on more visible posts?

Comment: Related [20 States Warn Facebook To Do Better At Fighting Hate And Discrimination | Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/alisondurkee/2020/08/05/20-states-warn-facebook-to-do-better-at-fighting-hate-and-discrimination/?sh=c59fed3343f8), [Sharing Our Actions on Stopping Hate | Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/business/news/sharing-actions-on-stopping-hate)

Comment: Related [Our Latest Steps to Keep Facebook Groups Safe | Facebook](https://about.fb.com/news/2020/09/keeping-facebook-groups-safe/)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO quality is more important than the volume. Also I think that the weight of your reports might be affected by your report history and the history of the content / users that you are reporting.

My recommendations

1. Take reports very seriously.
2. Make your reports brief but clear and complete.
3. Work colletively.

Rearding 2 and 3, I think that it will be very helpful for you to study the Facebook Community Standards and join a group of users interested on them.

---

From [5 ways to counter hate on social media](https://imix.org.uk/5-ways-to-counter-hate-on-social-media/)

> 4. Work collectively
>
> Trolls and haters gain more confidence in their fellowship. For this reason, when confronting them you should do the same. Get all your friends to report their profile as well, spread the word and build a network around you to feel empowered.  Also, there are many organisations who actively counteract hate speech with online campaigns, like [Silence Hate](http://www.silencehate.eu/author/silencehate/), [Don’t Feed the Trolls](https://www.counterhate.co.uk/dont-feed-the-trolls) and [Get the Trolls Out](https://www.getthetrollsout.org/). When you need support, contact them.